# Zip file not found for AWS Lambda Layer in GitHub through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I got the below error when I run my code

> Error: Unable to load "../../xxxx/yy.zip": open ../../xxxx/yy.zip: no such file or directory

tring to create layer for lambda as below through Terraform

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_layer" {
  filename   = "../../xxxx/yy.zip"
  layer_name = "xxxxlayer"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.11"]
}
```

Comment: Well, that means the path cannot be resolved

Comment: Are you sure you are running the commands in the correct directory?

Comment: yes, I am sure I ran it 4 months ago and it worked fine now I want to upgrade the runtime and got that error not being able to find the file

Answer (score 0):

As @paolo said in the comment - "Well, that means the path cannot be resolved"

This is a working example of creating a layer with automated building of a layer. Your layer should be created in a similar way because with that, you are always sure, that Terraform is using the correct paths, and preparing your layers in the same way.

Firstly you need to create a directories: `mkdir layer && cd layer && mkdir python`

```
resource "null_resource" "requests_layer" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "cd layer/python && pip install requests urllib3==1.26.15 -t ."
    working_dir = path.module
  }
}

data "archive_file" "requests_layer" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/layer"
  output_path = "${path.module}/layer.zip"

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.requests_layer
  ]
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "requests" {
  layer_name          = "requests"
  filename            = data.archive_file.requests_layer.output_path
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.11"]
  source_code_hash    = data.archive_file.requests_layer.output_base64sha256
}
```